# Assigning Strings in Private method

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I am currently writing a code that will convert an integer to roman numerals. I am attempting to create a method that assigns each digit of the int to either tenths hundredths or thousandths and converts it to a string, then add the strings together to get the final string of Roman numerals. However I see to be having issues, when I attempt to assign value to the Strings it does not allow me. Here is the code, advice would be great.
**Edit**- I attempted to clean up syntax a little, updated what I have. my main issue now is that the compiler states that the String assignments are duplicates, any advice how to solve?

```
private static String ConverttoNumerals (int newinteger){
   String Roman = "";
   int number = newinteger;
   int ones = number % 10;
   if (ones == 1){String Roman = "I";}
   else if ( ones == 2){String Roman = "II";}
   else if (ones == 3){String Roman = "III";}
   else if (ones == 4){String Roman = "IV";}
   else if (ones == 5){String Roman = "V";}
   else if (ones == 6){String Roman = "VI";}
   else if (ones == 7){String Roman = "VII";}
   else if (ones == 8 ){String Roman = "VII";}
   else if (ones == 9){String Roman = "IX";}
   else if (ones == 0){String Roman = "";
   int tenths = ((number / 10) % 10);
   String Romant="";
   if (tenths == 1){String Romant = "X";}
   else if (tenths == 2){String Romant = "XX";}
   else if (tenths == 3){String Romant = "XXX";}
   else if (tenths == 4){String Romant = "XL";}
   else if (tenths == 5){String Romant = "L";}
   else if (tenths == 6){String Romant = "LX";}
   else if (tenths == 7){String Romant = "LXX";}
   else if (tenths == 8 ){String Romant = "LXXX";}
   else if (tenths == 9){String Romant = "XC";}
```

Comment: You seems to have incredible amounts of syntax errors.

Comment: Where is the double quotes for assigning strings?

Comment: Please compile first then ask.

Comment: Rather than writting `String Romant = X` use `String Romant = "X"`.You need to put double quotes around string value.

Comment: It's not your assignments that are duplicates, it's your declarations.  Declare each variable once only, then assign it wherever you like.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using some String arrays .. can be further shortened and put into a loop using two dimensional arrays

```
public class Roman {
private static final String[] units =     {"", "I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"};
private static final String[] tens  =     {"","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC"};
private static final String[] hundreds =  {"","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM"};
private static final String[] thousands = {"","M","MM","MMM"};

public static String ConverttoNumerals (int newinteger){
    int n = newinteger;
    int digit = n/1000;
    String result = thousands[digit];

    n = n - digit*1000;
    digit = n/100;
    result = result + hundreds[digit];

    n = n -digit*100;
    digit = n/10;
    result = result + tens[digit];

    n = n - digit*10;
    result = result + units[digit];

    return result;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. String literals need to be in quotes: `String roman = "IX";`
2. Statements need to end with semicolons (`;`)
3. You should probably use a [`switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: 4. repeating `variable` declaration

Comment: What is the solution to repeating variable decleration

Comment: @user3250642 the solution is **don't do** repeating variable declaration -_-

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this Java stuff is it not possible for me to do this in the way I am attempting?

Comment: @user3250642  see the other answer. your homework is done. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ConverttoNumerals(53));
    }
    private static String ConverttoNumerals (int newinteger){
        String Roman = "";
        String Romant="";
        String Romanh = "";
        String Romanq = "";
        int number = newinteger;
        int ones = number % 10;
        if (ones == 1){ Roman = "I";}
        else if ( ones == 2){ Roman = "II";}
        else if (ones == 3){ Roman = "III";}
        else if (ones == 4){ Roman = "IV";}
        else if (ones == 5){ Roman = "V";}
        else if (ones == 6){ Roman = "VI";}
        else if (ones == 7){ Roman = "VII";}
        else if (ones == 8 ){ Roman = "VII";}
        else if (ones == 9){ Roman = "IX";}
        else if (ones == 0){ Roman = ""; }
        int tenths = ((number / 10) % 10);

        if (tenths == 1){ Romant = "X";}
        else if (tenths == 2){ Romant = "XX";}
        else if (tenths == 3){ Romant = "XXX";}
        else if (tenths == 4){ Romant = "XL";}
        else if (tenths == 5){ Romant = "L";}
        else if (tenths == 6){ Romant = "LX";}
        else if (tenths == 7){ Romant = "LXX";}
        else if (tenths == 8 ){ Romant = "LXXX";}
        else if (tenths == 9){ Romant = "XC";}
        int hundredths = ((number/100)%10)  ;
        if (hundredths == 1){ Romanh = "C";}
        else if (hundredths == 2){ Romanh = "CC";}
        else if (hundredths == 3){ Romanh = "CCC";}
        else if (hundredths == 4){ Romanh = "CD";}
        else if (hundredths == 5){ Romanh = "D";}
        else if (hundredths == 6){ Romanh = "DC";}
        else if (hundredths == 7){ Romanh = "DCC";}
        else if (hundredths == 8){ Romanh = "DCCC";}
        else if (hundredths == 9){ Romanh = "CM";}
        int thousandth = ((number/1000)%10);
        if (thousandth == 1){ Romanq = "M";}
        else if (thousandth == 2){ Romanq = "MM";}
        else if (thousandth == 3){ Romanq = "MMMM";}
        return  Romanq+Romanh+Romant+Roman;

    }
}
```

When you program in java please use naming conventions. I haven't used in this program because i am too lazy to edit all those. :-P

Comment: Wow that really helped a lot what is the difference between the two codes

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you. The problems in your code is specified in the previous answers. Happy learning Java.

Comment: _The problems in your code is specified in the previous answers_. Then that previous answer should be marked as accepted answer :)

Comment: I don't have any problem with that. :-)

Comment: It would be helpful if the down voter specify the reason to do so.